# extract data from a file using awk

Tags: shell, awk

How can I extract msg,sid from the below data:

```
alert tcp any any -> any any (msg: "this is a "dummy" rule (to test) the rule"; flow:to server; sid:1233; rev:1; no case; content: "nothing";)
```

and the output should be like:

**this is a "dummy" rule (to test) the rule | 1233**

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try with sed:

```
sed 's/.*msg: "\([^;]*\)";.*sid:\([0-9]*\).*/\1|\2/' file
```

It captures and output desired strings using backreference.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
awk -F'[:;]' '{print substr($2,3,(length($2)-3)),"| " $6}' f
this is a "dummy" rule (to test) the rule | 1233
```

**OR**

```
awk -F'[:;]' '{print substr($2,3,(length($2)-3)),v OFS $6}' v="|" f
this is a "dummy" rule (to test) the rule | 1233
```

**OR**

```
awk -v OFS=" | " -F'[:;]' '{gsub(/^[ "]+|["]+$/,"",$2);print $2 OFS $6}' f
this is a "dummy" rule (to test) the rule | 1233
```

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
$ echo "$txt"
alert tcp any any -> any any (msg: "this is a "dummy" rule (to test) the rule"; flow:to server; sid:1233; rev:1; no case; content: "nothing";)
```

You can use a Bash regex:

```
$ [[ $txt =~ msg:\ \"([^;]*)\"\;.*sid:([^;]*) ]] && 
         printf "%s | %s" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
this is a "dummy" rule (to test) the rule | 1233
```

Answer (score 0):

I would choose Perl since supports non-greedy operator and will work the same in all platforms (portable):

```
$ echo "$b"
alert tcp any any -> any any (msg: "this is a "dummy" rule (to test) the rule"; flow:to server; sid:1233; rev:1; no case; content: "nothing";)

$ echo "$b" |perl -pe 's/(.*msg: ?)(.*?)(\;.*?).*sid:(.*?)\;.*/\2|\4/'
"this is a "dummy" rule (to test) the rule"|1233
```

And also one more awk - GNU awk only:

```
$ echo "$b" |awk '{match($0,/(.*msg: )(\".+\"[^;]*)(.*sid:)(.[^;]*)/,a);print a[2] "|" a[4]}'
"this is a "dummy" rule (to test) the rule"|1233
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with awk and split fucntion :

```
awk -F ';' '
    {
                    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
            {
                            if(match($i,"msg")>0)
                    {
                            split($i, array2, ":")
                            message=array2[2]
                    }
           }

           print message
    }'  >> $file
```

done

and worked fine for me.

Comment: What is this variable/ column `update_date`, Looks like you missed something in the code..

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F\" '{print $2,$3,$4" | " substr($5,23,4)}' OFS='"' file

this is a "dummy" rule (to test) the rule | 1233
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.